# DeepLearning application runs well on localhost but crashes on cloud

Tags: python

Error: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                       
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app                                                                                          
    __import__(module_name)                                                                                                                                              
  File "/home/ateetk/mysite/Crop_Prediction/app.py", line 12, in <module>                                                                            
    model = pickle.load(open('/home/ateetk/mysite/Crop_Prediction/model.pkl', 'rb'))                                                                 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

Comment: did you install keras on the cloud?

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar, Yes I did